# Dcm4che Error Unrecognized PDU

Tags: runtime-error, dcm4che

I have the following error in a data retrieve on a Dcm4che Server:

```
2015-04-27 14:55:16,463 ERROR -> (TCPServer-1-2) [org.dcm4cheri.server.ServerImpl] org.dcm4che.net.PDUException: Unrecognized PDU[type=71, length=14113
95360]
org.dcm4che.net.PDUException: Unrecognized PDU[type=71, length=1411395360]
        at org.dcm4cheri.net.FsmImpl$2.parse(FsmImpl.java:1051)
        at org.dcm4cheri.net.FsmImpl.read(FsmImpl.java:512)
        at org.dcm4cheri.net.AssociationImpl.accept(AssociationImpl.java:287)
        at org.dcm4cheri.server.DcmHandlerImpl.handle(DcmHandlerImpl.java:248)
        at org.dcm4cheri.server.ServerImpl.run(ServerImpl.java:288)
        at org.dcm4cheri.util.LF_ThreadPool.join(LF_ThreadPool.java:174)
        at org.dcm4cheri.util.LF_ThreadPool$1.run(LF_ThreadPool.java:221)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Likely a mismatch in aet name or settings.

Imagine your dcmrcv server as a house. It has a mailbox address that is just listening for stuff.

Now when you use say dcmsnd from somewhere else you must make sure it sends its information to the correct address. If you get ip and port right you may see a blurb come out on dcmrcv but it won't accept it.

Simplify your test as much as possible. Here is a very simple dcmrcv:
dcmrcv TRANSFERTEST@10.1.50.75:104 -dest "C:\Temp"

call this from another cmd prompt:
 dcmsnd CONI_STORAGE@dev.capsurecloud.com:11012 "C:\modalities\xa" -L WST

Note: That WST is not needed, but is the aet name of my application. Read the confluence documentation for more arguments.

Most the time i see your error is becuase the aetname@ip is mismatch or one side is sending or listening for tls and the other side doesn't match.